# Spark - How to join current and previous records in a DataFrame and assign an original field to all such occurences

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to scan through a Hive table and add values from the first record in a sequence to all linked records.

The logic would be:-

1. Find the first record (where previous_id is blank).
2. Find the next record (current_id = previous_id).
3. Repeat until there are no more linked records.
4. Add columns from original record to all linked records.
5. Output results to a Hive table.

Example Source Data:-

```
current_id previous_id start_date
---------- ----------- ----------
100                    01/01/2001
200        100         02/02/2002
300        200         03/03/2003
```

Example Output Data:-

```
current_id start_date
---------- ----------
100        01/01/2001
200        01/01/2001
300        01/01/2001
```

I can achieve this by creating two DataFrames from the source table and performing multiple joins. However, this approach does not seem ideal as data has to be cached to avoid re-querying the source data with each iteration.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: The example is too limited. Can you have 500 pointing to 400 which points to nothing? I assume so. Not convinced your caching is an issue.

Comment: i am assuming the current IDs are always asc.

Comment: Is this set of data possible?         (100, None, '2001/01/01'),
        (200, 100,  '2002/02/02'),
        (300, 200,  '2003/03/03'),
        (400, None, '2005/01/01'),
        (500, 400,  '2006/02/02'),
        (600, 300,  '2007/02/02'),
        (700, 600,  '2008/02/02'),

Comment: If so, then the fact is that there is not really  grouping id/key. Can you verify if the data as per above is possible?

Comment: So, I have an answer with looping, but I would suggest embellishing your data with some form of grouping key which obviates looping. You will need to save and read from data source yourself but that is the easy part. The example was not satisfactory in terms of data, so I weighed it down. It is a good question I have to say, but ...

Comment: From my simplified sample data current_id 100 is the first record in the series, 200 the second, and 300 the last. There is no overall grouping key and the numbering is not sequential. Thanks for the replies, I will see if any will work for my use case.

Comment: Well, they both do Sir, but I learnt something from the other answer which works in this case more elegantly, like ORACLE connect by. But good for the soul.

Comment: @DinoG let us know how it goes

Comment: How did you rate answers btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that I am not sure sits well with Spark.

There is a lack of a grouping id / key for the data.

Not sure how Catalyst would be able to optimize this - will look at at a later point in time. Memory errors if too large?

Have made the data more complicated, and this does work. Here goes:

```
# No grouping key evident, more a linked list with asc current_ids.
# Added more complexity to the example.
# Questions open on performance at scale. Interested to see how well Catalyst handles this.
# Need really some grouping id/key in the data.

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Started from dataframe.
# Some more realistic data? At least more complex.
columns = ['current_id', 'previous_id', 'start_date']
vals = [
        (100, None, '2001/01/01'),
        (200, 100,  '2002/02/02'),
        (300, 200,  '2003/03/03'),
        (400, None, '2005/01/01'),
        (500, 400,  '2006/02/02'),
        (600, 300,  '2007/02/02'),
        (700, 600,  '2008/02/02'),
        (800, None, '2009/02/02'),
        (900, 800,  '2010/02/02')  
       ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("trans")

# Starting data. The null / None entries. 
df2 = spark.sql("""
                   select * 
                     from trans 
                    where previous_id is null
                """)
df2.cache
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("trans_0")

# Loop through the stuff based on traversing the list elements until exhaustion of data, and, write to dynamically named TempViews.
# May need to checkpoint? Depends on depth of chain of linked items.
# Spark not well suited to this type of processing.  
dfX_cnt  = 1
cnt = 1

while (dfX_cnt != 0): 
  tabname_prev = 'trans_' + str(cnt-1)
  tabname = 'trans_' + str(cnt) 

  query = "select t2.current_id, t2.previous_id, t1.start_date from {} t1, trans t2 where t1.current_id = t2.previous_id".format(tabname_prev)
  dfX = spark.sql(query)
  dfX.cache

  dfX_cnt = dfX.count()
  if (dfX_cnt!=0):
      #print('Looping for dynamic creation of TempViews')
      dfX.createOrReplaceTempView(tabname)
      cnt=cnt+1

# Reduce the TempViews all to one DF. Can reduce an array of DF's as well, but could not find my notes here in this regard.
# Will memory errors occur? 

from pyspark.sql.types import *
fields = [StructField('current_id', LongType(), False),
          StructField('previous_id', LongType(), True),
          StructField('start_date',  StringType(), False)]
schema = StructType(fields)
dfZ = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

for i in range(0,cnt,1):
    tabname = 'trans_' + str(i)
    query = "select * from {}".format(tabname)
    df = spark.sql(query)
    dfZ = dfZ.union(df)

# Show final results.
dfZ.select('current_id', 'start_date').sort(col('current_id')).show()
```

returns:

```
+----------+----------+
|current_id|start_date|
+----------+----------+
|       100|2001/01/01|
|       200|2001/01/01|
|       300|2001/01/01|
|       400|2005/01/01|
|       500|2005/01/01|
|       600|2001/01/01|
|       700|2001/01/01|
|       800|2009/02/02|
|       900|2009/02/02|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this using [GraphFrames Connected components](https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#connected-components)

It will help you avoid writing the checkpointing and looping logic yourself. Essentially you create a graph from the `current_id` and `previous_id` pairs and use GraphFrames to the component for each vertex. That resulting DataFrame can then be joined to the original DataFrame to get the `start_date`.

```
from graphframes import *

sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/chk")

input = spark.createDataFrame([
  (100, None, "2001-01-01"),
  (200, 100, "2002-02-02"),
  (300, 200, "2003-03-03"),
  (400, None, "2004-04-04"),
  (500, 400, "2005-05-05"),
  (600, 500, "2006-06-06"),
  (700, 300, "2007-07-07")
], ["current_id", "previous_id", "start_date"])

input.show()

vertices = input.select(input.current_id.alias("id"))

edges = input.select(input.current_id.alias("src"), input.previous_id.alias("dst"))

graph = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

result = graph.connectedComponents()

result.join(input.previous_id.isNull(), result.component == input.current_id)\
  .select(result.id.alias("current_id"), input.start_date)\
  .orderBy("current_id")\
  .show()
```

Results in the following output:

```
+----------+----------+
|current_id|start_date|
+----------+----------+
|       100|2001-01-01|
|       200|2001-01-01|
|       300|2001-01-01|
|       400|2004-04-04|
|       500|2004-04-04|
|       600|2004-04-04|
|       700|2001-01-01|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Equivalent of Oracle connect by?

Comment: Not familiar with Oracle's connect by, but the link I posted has an explanation of what it is in GraphFrames.

Comment: It amounts to the same thing, nice to know. neo4j well aware of but not this, until now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions posted here. After trying various approaches I have gone with the following solution which works for multiple iterations (e.g. 20 loops), and does not cause any memory issues.

The "Physical Plan" is still huge, but caching means most of the steps are skipped, keeping performance acceptable.

```
input = spark.createDataFrame([
    (100, None, '2001/01/01'),
    (200, 100,  '2002/02/02'),
    (300, 200,  '2003/03/03'),
    (400, None, '2005/01/01'),
    (500, 400,  '2006/02/02'),
    (600, 300,  '2007/02/02'),
    (700, 600,  '2008/02/02'),
    (800, None, '2009/02/02'),
    (900, 800,  '2010/02/02')
], ["current_id", "previous_id", "start_date"])

input.createOrReplaceTempView("input")

cur = spark.sql("select * from input where previous_id is null")
nxt = spark.sql("select * from input where previous_id is not null")

cur.cache()
nxt.cache()

cur.createOrReplaceTempView("cur0")
nxt.createOrReplaceTempView("nxt")

i = 1
while True:
    spark.sql("set table_name=cur" + str(i - 1))
    cur = spark.sql(
        """
            SELECT  nxt.current_id  as current_id,  
                    nxt.previous_id as previous_id, 
                    cur.start_date  as start_date       
            FROM    ${table_name}   cur, 
                    nxt             nxt 
            WHERE   cur.current_id = nxt.previous_id 
        """).cache()
    cur.createOrReplaceTempView("cur" + str(i))
    i = i + 1
    if cur.count() == 0:
        break

for x in range(0, i):
    spark.sql("set table_name=cur" + str(x))
    cur = spark.sql("select * from ${table_name}")
    if x == 0:
        out = cur
    else:
        out = out.union(cur)
```